# find duplicates in php multidimentional array and place them in a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [name] => abc
                    [age] => 21

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 456
                   [name] => abc
                   [age] => 25
                  )
             [2] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 789
                   [name] => ghi
                   [age] => 40
                  )
               )
             )
```

what i want to do is find any duplicates name in that array and place that in a new array.So finally my array have to be like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [name] => abc
                    [age] => 21

                )

             [1] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 789
                   [name] => ghi
                   [age] => 40
                  )
           )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 456
                   [name] => abc
                   [age] => 25

           )
         )

             )
```

I'm struggling on how to do that.can any body pls help me to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to loop over the array (foreach), get each name and compare to all other names using a nested loop.

Comment: I'm new to multidimentional array and can loop through the array and can acess values after that how can i process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple foreach for this, you could just push the duplicate array to the next dimension if it sees one. Example:

```
$values = array(
    array(
        array('id' => 123, 'name' => 'abc', 'age', 21),
        array('id' => 456, 'name' => 'abc', 'age', 25),
        array('id' => 789, 'name' => 'ghi', 'age', 40),
    ),
);

foreach($values as $batch) {
    $temp = array();
    foreach($batch as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($temp[$value['name']])) {
            $temp[$value['name']] = $value; // temporary storage
        } else {
            unset($batch[$key]);
            $values[][] = $value; // push it outside this batch
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($values);
```